# Ubuntu doesn't load after logging in with sudo account

Tags: dual-boot, login, root

So I got Ubuntu yesterday running on my Acer Aspire V5-122P. I really love it. There's a learning curve indeed, but I think I got used to it. I love installing programs via the terminal, dunno why!

Anyways, just a few minutes ago I was downloading some file and was getting ready to extract that file. The file got stuck halfway and never finished. How weird. So I redownload that file and Ubuntu screams at me something like "0 bytes free in the filesystem" or something like that. So uhm I click the clean it button and suddenly Chrome closes. Chrome has been uninstalled and Firefox as well. So I try opening the Terminal and try to install Chromium. Yup, nothing installed even though it seems to says so.

Dash suddenly starts glitching and I can't search properly anymore. For example "No searches have been found" on the Applications page of Dash. Ugh. Time to restart the laptop.

Laptop boots into Windows 8.1, fine. I then go to the Advanced Boot Options and boot Ubuntu from there. It starts up fine. Yay? I type my username, the white dots and such disappear and Ubuntu is stuck on that screen with the cursor. Nothing pop ups. I even waited 10 minutes. Okay, let's restart the laptop again.

Guest session seems to work fine, except that Dash only shows a / folder and Ubuntu screamed at me saying that there's 0 bytes free on the filesystem. Uhhh... I have a bad feeling about this. I Win + L and it just shows a black screen. Arrgh. Logout then. I try to login using my normal account and it shows the same problem as before.

I'm typing this from Windows 8.1... ugh got so used to the stableness of Ubuntu. I can't stand Windows anymore after loving Ubuntu :(

Any solutions guys?